# Flutter: purchases stream is empty and attempted purchase throws 'pending transaction for the same product identifier'

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm using the Flutter [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) plugin, `v0.3.3+1`.

While testing on iOS, I began a purchase but cancelled mid-way through. After that, whenever I try the purchase again, I get an exception with this message:

> There is a pending transaction for the same product identifier

I have a listener setup on the purchase stream (code below) to complete the purchases. But the stream is not emitting any events.

```
_purchaseListener = InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.purchaseUpdatedStream.listen((purchases) {
  purchases.forEach((purchase) async {
    if (purchase.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased) //...
    if (purchase.pendingCompletePurchase) {
      //Complete purchase (retrying as Google Play refunds after 3 days if this does not succeed)
      retry<BillingResultWrapper>(() async {
        final completion = await InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.completePurchase(purchase);
        const errors = {BillingResponse.error, BillingResponse.serviceUnavailable};
        if (errors.contains(completion.responseCode)) throw Exception();
        return completion;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You must clean the pending transaction first.

To do that, first import

```
import 'package:in_app_purchase_storekit/store_kit_wrappers.dart';
```

and then call

```dart
final paymentWrapper = SKPaymentQueueWrapper();
final transactions = await paymentWrapper.transactions();
transactions.forEach((transaction) async {
    await paymentWrapper.finishTransaction(transaction);
});
```

Comment: How can i acces SKPaymentQueueWrapper() . I have got an error The function 'SKPaymentQueueWrapper' isn't defined.

Comment: I fixed -> import 'package:in_app_purchase_ios/store_kit_wrappers.dart';

Comment: Where is the best place to use this? I've tried calling this at the start of my listener, but I am stuck in a loop where I always have 99 Restore transactions returned (on iOS). But my device has a canceled subscription. Lost on how to fix this. To note, this is in the Sandbox Environment.

Comment: Still relevant fix...

Comment: Unfortunately store_kit_wrappers can't be imported anymore; any ideas? The IAP lib for flutter doesn't support transaction cleaning ..

Comment: For anyone still looking this is the library reference
https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase_storekit

Comment: import 'package:in_app_purchase_storekit/store_kit_wrappers.dart';

Comment: Using this, I get `Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(storekit_finish_transaction_exception, NSInvalidArgumentException, Cannot finish a purchasing transaction, null)`

Answer (score 0):

The stream was not emitting any events in `debug` mode, so the purchase was never coming through and being completed.

Testing in `release` mode, it works perfectly.

Comment: how did you manage to test that in release mode with the sandbox user?

Comment: Perhaps more to the point, how did you manage to clear the queue once you figured out what was going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

No need any other library, just use of `in_app_purchase: ^3.1.11`.

The best approach is to start a timer and ready to check the `pendingCompletePurchase`  status every 1 second, once it is true, the transaction is really really really completed.

Below are my code:

````dart
  late List<ProductDetails> purchaseProducts = [];
  late List<PurchaseDetails> purchasedList = [];
  Timer? timer;

  @override
  void initState() { 
    super.initState(); 
    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) {
      if (purchasedList.isNotEmpty) {
        for (int a = 0; a < purchasedList.length; a++) {
          if (purchasedList[a].pendingCompletePurchase) {
            completedPurchase(purchasedList[a]);
            purchasedList.removeAt(a);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }

......

  void _listenToPurchaseUpdated(List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) async { 
    purchasedList = purchaseDetailsList;
    for (var detail in purchaseDetailsList) {
      if (detail.status == PurchaseStatus.pending) { 
        setState(() { showIndicator = true; });
      } else {
        if (detail.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased || detail.status == PurchaseStatus.restored) { 
          showMsg(detail.status == PurchaseStatus.restored ? "Restored Successfully" : "Purchase Successfully");
          Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () async {
            setState(() { showIndicator = false; });
            if (detail.pendingCompletePurchase) { 
              completedPurchase(detail);
              // Successfully payment 
            } else {
              purchasedList.add(detail);
            }
          });  
        } else if (detail.status == PurchaseStatus.canceled) {
          Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () async {
            setState(() { showIndicator = false; });
          });
          showMsg("Purchase Cancalled"); 
        } else if (detail.status == PurchaseStatus.error) {
          setState(() { showIndicator = false; });
          var s = detail.error?.message ?? "Unexpected error when the purchase occurred";
          showMsg("code: ${detail.error?.code} \nmessage: $s");
        }
      }
    }
  }

```
````